# Team Foundation Server 2015: Authentication with JavaScript

Tags: tfs

I am running a Team Foundation Server 2015 on an IIS Server and I try to create a small JavaScript/jQuery App to display all builds / build definitions.

When I call following URL, I get all build definitions as json string: [apiUrl]/_apis/build/definitions/

When I run following jQuery-Code:

```
$.get( "[apiUrl]/_apis/build/definitions/", function( data ) {
  console.warn( data );
});
```

I get a 401 (Unauthorized) IIS error page.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What account is the app pool running as? Is that account authorized to access TFS?

Comment: Yes, the account is authorized to access TFS and all the data I try to fetch. Calling the URL directly in my browser will return me the correct json-string, but not, if I try to get with via jQuery/Ajax.